# GitHub hidden branches

Tags: github

When I do a `git branch -r` I see 52 branches in my remote GitHub repo. When I look at the GH web page showing branches for the same repo, there are 7. I haven't used GH a ton, am I missing something? Why isn't it showing the other 45 branches? Because they are merged maybe? I can still check these hidden branches out, but the are not on GitHub's web UI.

EDIT: it's not just because they are merged, because *some* merged branches show.

Comment: AFAIK, -r is for listing tracking branches in local repo. Did you try cloning the repo again and run ```git branch -r``` and see if you get a different output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, GitHub will show:

- the default branch
- the active branches
- a *subset* of the stalled branches (as in [`moby/moby`](https://github.com/moby/moby/branches)): that would explain why you don't see all branches (assuming they have not been pruned on the remote  side, and deleted)

As commented, cloning remains the surest way to ensure all the (remote tracking) branches are there.

---

The [OP cdmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721065/cdmo) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54045695/github-hidden-branches/54048495?noredirect=1#comment94988136_54048495) the branches are *not* there locally after a **[`git fetch --prune`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#git-fetch--p)**:

> I had a misunderstanding that git would automatically remove references to deleted branches on the remote locally, especially with a `git fetch --all`.

Comment: I mean, running `git branch -r` shows me all the branches that exist on the repo at GitHub, and I can easily check any of them out. They exist. GitHub just doesn't tell you *at all* that they still exist. Like, not even a "there are 45 branches that are hidden because of whatever reason." I am used to GitLab. It doesn't hide branches ever and even has a handy "Delete merged branches" button. I'm just surprised.

Comment: Can you try and type a `git fetch --prune`, and then check if `git branch -r` still list 45 branches?

Comment: As long as you are holding on to your old clone, you may see old tracking branches. Either try cloning the repo or try ```fetch --prunch``` on existing clone and check if local and github show same number of branches or not. BTW, github also shows delete branch button immediately after you merge a PR.

Comment: The branches are there. I can check them out. The branches not being there isn't the problem. The problem is that GitHub omits the existence of all of these branches *completely*. No notice of their existence or the fact that they are hidden. Kind of annoying.

Comment: @cdmo Still, are the branches still there (locally)  *after* a `git fetch --prune`?

Comment: Nope! Thanks for the help. I had a misunderstanding that git would automatically remove references to deleted branches on the remote locally, especially with a `git fetch --all`. I don't know why I haven't noticed this behavior in the past.

Comment: @cdmo Great! I have included my comment and yours in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Happy to mark this the answer with the edit, thanks again